# How to explicitly declare a cv::Mat type as part of a OpenCV library function

Tags: c++, opencv

I am currently trying to concatenate cv::Mat objects using [`cv::hconcat(std::vector<cv::Mat> vector_of_mats, cv::Mat dest)`](http://answers.opencv.org/question/1368/concatenating-matrices/). However, I need the destination cv::Mat to be of type `CV_32FC1` rather than the default `CV_8UC1`.

I tried constructing the destination cv::Mat as:

```
    descriptor = cv::Mat::zeros(tmp.size(), 256, CV_32FC1);
    cv::hconcat(vec, descriptor);
```

But that still produces a `CV_8UC1` `cv::Mat` for `descriptor`. The type of `cv::Mat` in the vector is `CV_8UC1`. Is that where my problem lies?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your suspicions are correct! The type of the `cv::Mat` is taken from the **source**.

A quick look at the source code of `cv::hconcat` confirms this:

```
void cv::hconcat(const Mat* src, size_t nsrc, OutputArray _dst) {
    ....
    _dst.create( src[0].rows, totalCols, src[0].type()); // Type taken from src
    ....
}

void cv::hconcat(InputArray _src, OutputArray dst)
{
    std::vector<Mat> src;
    _src.getMatVector(src);
    hconcat(!src.empty() ? &src[0] : 0, src.size(), dst);
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to declare a cv::Mat with a type without specifying a size? I looked at the *long* list of constructors and couldn't find one, but I thought perhaps there may be some way.

Comment: @marcman Absolutely, I assume you know the number of columns (256), so you can simply do `descriptors = cv::Mat(0, 256, CV_32FC1)`, and then call `descriptors.push_back(vec)`, assuming vec also has 256 columns. Note: I'm not sure what sort of trouble you could run in to here if they are different types, never tried it.